# Функция rename в PHP, не хватает прав

Tags: php, openserver

Использую функцию `rename()`, возникает ошибка. Как решить?

> Warning:
> rename(C:/serv/OpenServer/domains/localhost/content/uploads/2014/06/100-Рё-500-РїРѕРёСЃРєРѕРІС‹С…-С„СЂР°Р·.jpg,C:/serv/OpenServer/domains/localhost/content/uploads/2011/06/)
> [<a
> href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]:
> Отказано в доступе. (code: 5) in
> C:\serv\OpenServer\domains\localhost\renamer.php
> on line 19

P.S. Пробую на локалхосте, стоит Opensever последний.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй OpenServer запустить от имени администратора.